# Como deshabilito la ejecucion en paralelo de dos projectos de testing (.dll) en xUnit y .Net Core

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, test

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un projecto de testing que utiliza xUnit para llevar adelante los tests funcionales y de integracion en una app desarrollada en .Net Core 2.2

La solucion se ve algo similar a esto:

```
...

    Server //folder
        Server //csproj
            AuthController.cs //c# class
        Server.FunctionalTests //csproj
            AuthControllerFunctionalTests.cs //c# class

    Domain //folder
        Domain //csproj
            AuthService.cs //c# class
        Domain.IntegrationTests //csproj
            AuthService.csIntegrationTest //c# class

...
```

Donde en el csproj "Server" se encuentran los controllers, que delegan la responsabilidad de la logica de negocios a los servicios que se encuentran en el proyecto Domain.

Ahora bien, tenemos escritos una serie de test funcionales para esos controller, donde a grandes rasgos creamos [un test server y un cliente segun las funcionalidades que brinda Microsoft en esta clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?view=aspnetcore-3.0)
y los hacemos interactar de forma que podamos verificar que objeto/respuesta devuelve un controller ante determinada llamada.

[Tambien hacemos uso de la funcionalidad "collection fixtures" de xunit para compartir el contexto entre todas las clases pertenecientes al projecto (Server.FunctionalTests)](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context), instanciando un solo dbContext para todas las clases pertenecientes a una misma dll

Y como todas las clases que forman parte de la .dll Server.FunctionalTests tiene el mismo decorador [Collection], posibilita que todos los test dentro de esa dll corran de forma secuencial y no originan ningun inconveniente de concurrencia

El codigo de los test funcionales es algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Verify api/Auth [Get] is returning Accepted [202] when data is valid")]
    [Trait("Category", "Functional-Test")]
    public async Task GivenAuthControllerGet_WhenDataIsValid_ShouldReturnAndAccepted202()
    {
        //Arrange
        Context.SetupDatabaseForTesting(); // Este helper method elimina todos los datos de la base
        var authDto = new AuthDto(){ User = "test", Password = "test"} // Creo una entidad para agregarla a la base
        Context.SeedDatabaseWith(authDto); // Este helper method agrega la entidad a base de datos y guarda los cambios

        //Act
        var httpResultData = await HttpCallAsync(HttpVerb.GET, $"{ControllerName}/"); 
        //Este helper method hace la llamada Http al controller y guarda en httpResultData lo que devolvio el controller

        //Asserts
        ...
    }
```

Para los test de integracion, hacemos lo mismo pero nuestro objeto de testeo ya no son los controllers, sino los servicios. Otra vez, compartimos un dbContexto bajo el feature de xUnit "Collection Fixtures".

Ambos tipos de test (funcionales/integracion) corren sobre una misma base de datos creada exclusivamente para testeo: "DB_TESTING" con una unica connectionstring

Los test de integracion son similares a lo siguiente:

```
    [Fact(DisplayName = "Verify that given a valid model, auth service should be valid")]
    public void GivenAuthServiceLogin_WhenSendingValidData_ShouldLoginWithoutProblems()
    {
        //Arrange
        Context.SetupDatabaseForTesting(); // Este helper method elimina todos los datos de la base
        var authDto = new AuthDto(){ User = "test", Password = "test"} // Creo una entidad para agregarla a la base
        Context.SeedDatabaseWith(authDto); // Este helper method agrega la entidad a base de datos y guarda los cambios

        //Act
        var result = _authService.Login(authDto); //Envio el modelo al metodo que quiero testear

        //Asserts
        ...
    }
```

Hasta aca no hay problema, ya que corriendo los test de forma secuencial, funciona como se espera.
El problema surge cuando a traves de la linea de comandos de powershell ejecuto un "dotnet test", y como (entiendo) por default por linea de comandos xunit intenta ejecutar los test en diferentes dll en paralelo y se me generan errores de concurrencia:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Transaction (Process ID 52) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

Como solucion, lo que se me ocurrio es simplemente cambiar el comportamiento default de xunit, y correr esas dos .dll que estan generando el deadlock de forma secuencial segun [la documentacion que refiere agregar un xunit.runner.json para cambiar el comportamiento defaul de xUnit](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files), pero por alguna razon no esta obedeciendo al json.
A alguien se le ocurre como puedo taclear este problema?

Comment: Tuve un problema parecido, pero lo resolvi de varias maneras:  Usando InMemoryDatabase, pero en tu caso que tienes una base de datos de Testing creo que es mas fácil consultar dato y verificar despues de guardalos, en mi caso yo tuve que poner funcion para validar la existencia de los datos cada vez, tu problema se puede arreglar utilizando `using` para no dejar transacciones o conexiones abiertas, pero tendrias que cambiar un poco la forma como creas el context...

Comment: Si creas la instancia del context cada vez... no tendrias este problema... y creo que no afectara porque tienes una BD real no un InMemory, así que es la acción que yo tomaria `using(var context = new Context())`...

Comment: Bueno, no estoy segura si eso arreglaría deadlock... U_U, una de las mayores causas de deadlock es cuando intentas hacer un update en tablas que no tiene indices, en tu caso tienes alguna tabla sin indice o sin llave?